# Related issues with the TextPath of SvgText in C # programming SVG

Tags: c#, svg

I know that in SVG drawing, if you want to render text in a specific path, you can use XML <textPath> to achieve it. something like:

```
<path id="path1" d="M 0, 0 a200,200 0 0,1 250,5" />
  <text textLength="200" transform="translate(75, 180)" font-size="24" style="fill:#FF0000;">
    <textPath href="#path1">
       textPathTest
    </textPath>
  </text>
```

But if I want to use the Svg. SvgDocument class in c# to draw a picture, how do I assign a value to the textPath property of SvgText? The code snippet is as follows

```
SvgDocument svgDocument = new SvgDocument();
SvgText text1 = new SvgText();
text1.Text = "textPathTest";
text1.FontSize = 24;
text1.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
text1.TextLength = 200;
//var svgpath = "M 0, 0 a200,200 0 0,1 250,5";
                
text1.Transforms = new Svg.Transforms.SvgTransformCollection();
text1.Transforms.Add(new Svg.Transforms.SvgTranslate(75, 180));
svgDocument.Children.Add(text1);
```

I searched a lot of information but couldn't find any related SVG drawings in C#

Comment: There is no guarantee that your library will support every feature of the svg standard. If your current library does not support this you may need to pick another library, write your own svg-library, or find some other workaround.